# SMS_ReplicationLinkSummary Server WMI Class - Status values

Tags: windows, monitoring, wmi, sccm, sms

I'm trying to monitor a SCCM environment via a non-SCOM system that primarily uses WMI as a management interface.

I've found the following class:
[**SMS_ReplicationLinkSummary** Server WMI Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj874310.aspx)

There are numerous 'status' fields in this class that seem like they could give me what I'm looking for. The problem, however, is that I get values that aren't documented on the MSDN site.

I get a value of **125** for **Site1Status** as well as **Site2Status**

This is useless to me if I cannot translate **125** to something a normal human being can read.

Anyone familiar with these?

Comment: What do you want to monitor? Replication link status or site status?

Comment: ReplicationLinkStatus

Comment: Apologies, I also  need the Site1 and Site2 status

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Site status = 125 means **active**. You can use SQL Function to get result, like:

> SELECT dbo.fnGetSiteStatusFriendlyName(125)

The property *LinkStatus* is overall replication link status. 2 means **Active**. Any value other than 2 is not good.

Comment: Just want to know if these helped?

Comment: Apologies...I never forget to mark an answer when I get one...not sure why I missed this...many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the function to see how it does it -  i found this....

```
        WHEN 100 THEN 'SITE_INSTALLING'                  
        WHEN 105 THEN 'SITE_INSTALL_COMPLETE'            
        WHEN 110 THEN 'INACTIVE'                         
        WHEN 115 THEN 'INITIALIZING'                     
        WHEN 120 THEN 'MAINTENANCE_MODE'                 
        WHEN 125 THEN 'ACTIVE'             <----              
        WHEN 130 THEN 'DETACHING'                        
        WHEN 135 THEN 'READY_TO_DETACH'                  
        WHEN 199 THEN 'STATUS_UNKNOWN'                   
        WHEN 200 THEN 'SITE_RECOVERED'                        
        WHEN 205 THEN 'SITE_PREPARE_FOR_RECOVERY'             
        WHEN 210 THEN 'SITE_PREPARED_FOR_RECOVERY'            
        WHEN 215 THEN 'REPLCONFIG_REINITIALIZING'             
        WHEN 220 THEN 'REPLCONFIG_REINITIALIZED'              
        WHEN 225 THEN 'RECOVERY_IN_PROGRESS'                  
        WHEN 230 THEN 'RECOVERING_DELTAS'                     
        WHEN 250 THEN 'RECOVERY_RETRY'                        
        WHEN 255 THEN 'RECOVERY_FAILED'
```